# Minecraft прокси

Tags: ruby

Делаю прокси для серверов майнкрафта, уже долгое время не могу понять, что делать после создания TCP сокета, в каком порядке нужно посылать байты и как работают кодировки. Прикладываю сайт, на котором описывается протокол https://wiki.vg/Protocol_Encryption. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Если Вы деаете именно прокси - Вам вообще на уровне прокси необязательно понимать протокол. Прокси просто пересылает данные в обе стороны. Я предполагаю, что Вы хотите сделать нечто другое - для чего может действительно понадобиться протокол. В таком случае - исправьте вопрос?

Comment: М.б. хочет сделать читы или угонять пароли. Совсем недавно видел заказ для "прокси" для заведомо чужого сервера Rust. Новый отечественный тренд.